# What do we decide discrete probability vs binomial probability

Tags: probability

everyone. Recently I am thinking we should we use decide discrete probability vs binomial probability.

For example,

There are 55 students in statistic course this semester. Suppose the probability that a student live in the Place A is 0.02. Let X be the total number of students from statistic course who lives in Place A.

What is the probability that at most 3 students live in place A?

My effort:

P(at most 3 students live in place A) = P(x=0) + P(x=1) + P(x=2) + P(x=3)
= 0.98^55 + 0.98^54 * 0.02 + 0.98^53 * 0.02^2 + 0.98^52 * 0.02^3
=0.68579

However, I can also use binomial distribution to do it

55C0 *  0.02^0 * 0.98^55 + 55C1 * 0.02^1 * 0.98^54 + 55C2 * 0.02^2 * 0.98^53 + 55C3 * 0.02^3 *0.98^52
= 0.9757

The result can be quite different, so I am thinking when should I use those two methods, and which one is correct. Thank you!!

Comment: If I asked you what's the probability that students 1 - 54 don't live in place A, and student 55 lives in place A, the answer would be $.98^{54} \cdot .02$. However, if I ask you what's the probability that exactly one student lives in place A then the answer is different (because that one student could be student 55, or it could be student 54, or student 53, or so on).

Comment: Quite... you can think of living at $A$ as a success and not living at $A$ as a fail.  In  your first attempt, you only counted where all fails occurred before all successes.  In your second attempt you allowed these to mix.  The second is the correct one to use.

Comment: Consider the problem with flipping two fair coins in sequence.  We know that we should have had exactly zero or exactly one or exactly two of those coins flip as heads.  That should imply that $\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1)+\Pr(X=2)=1$ should have been true if we used the correct distribution, which it will be if we used binomial distribution correctly.  You'll find it does not equal $1$ if you incorrectly used the logic from your first attempt.